# How to check if a button exists?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, element

I'm learning to create a chrome extension. I want to create an extension to find a button and show alerts that found it

The button is

```
<button class="bt bt-sm text-white btn-flashing"
style="background-color: #fd7e14; margin:3px" disabled="">ABC - 01</button>
```

So how i can write a script to find that?

I have a script for showing the alert

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() { 
        alert("found it");
})
```

Thank you.

Comment: Use a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/) that checks for the button in the page.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/content_scripts/) to check for the presence of the button.

For example:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(){
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
        code: 'document.querySelector("button.bt.bt-sm.text-white.btn-flashing")'
    }, function(result) {
        if (result[0]) {
            alert('found it');
        } else {
            alert('not found');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. It works if the page is just clear HTML. If the page is rendered by JS. How to search after DOM render completes?

Comment: You can use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) and [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/messaging/).

Comment: I'm new to that. Could you help to code to find the button? Thank you so much :D

Answer (score 1):

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() { 
//Checking if there are any results of the button with that class
        if(document.querySelectorAll('.bt bt-sm text-white btn-flashing').length >= 1){
//Found results of the button

}else{
//Found no results of the button

});
```

All this code says is if there are more than 0 occurances of ".bt bt-sm text white btn-flashing" then it found results.